# What does [n] mean here?

Tags: fourier-analysis, notation, boolean-algebra

[image]

I am reading [this document](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/sigtacs/references/S02E03-fourier.pdf).

What is the meaning of $[n]$ ?
Is it power set of $\{1,2,3...n\}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's just the set $\{ 1,2,\dots,n \}$. If you look at the notation carefully, you see that $S$ is written a *subset* of that set; if they meant the powerset they would have written $S$ as an *element* of the powerset.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the set $\{ 1,2,\ldots,n\}$.